# Error when I try to open pdf file from PdfParser in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I wanto to read the text into PDF File with PHP. So, for this, I have used PdfParser library. So I have build this code:

```
<?php
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
include '/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php';


$parser = new Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
echo "pippo";
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('Ricardo.pdf');  
echo "pippo1";
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo "pippo2";
echo $text;//all text from Ricardo.pdf

?>
```

Now, if I try to open this page I can read only

> pippo

and I can't see other print.
I don't see some error on the page. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like `Ricardo.pdf` is missing. As you wrote on last line **all text from** `mypdf.pdf`. Do you want content from `mypdf.pdf` or from `Ricardo.pdf`?

Comment: Ricardo.pdf is a PDF file with only text

Comment: I have a similar issue here. Are you on php 5.3?